# FormKit: how to do async/server-side validation?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, validation, vuejs3, formkit

How can I do async/server-side validation using [FormKit](https://formkit.com/) (with Vue3)? Not only on submit but also after user removes focus from the input.

Basic validation example:

```
<FormKit
  type="text"
  label="Number"
  validation="required|number|between:20,50"
  validation-visibility="live"
  help="Enter a number between 20 and 50."
/>
```

Don't find any examples or mentions anywhere other than the [documentation](https://formkit.com/essentials/validation) mention async once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Creating a custom async rule***

In FormKit, validation rules are just functions that accept a [core node](https://formkit.com/essentials/architecture#node) and return a boolean value — `true` for a passing validation, and `false` for failing:

```
const rules = {
  async checkUsername ({ value }) {
    return new Promise((r) => setTimeout(() => r(value === 'foouser'), 500))
  }
}
```

The `checkUsername` async rule above will pass validation if the user types in `foouser` as their username. Notice the rule is wrapped in a `rules` object, which allows you to define as many rules as you want.

***Adding your async rule to your input***

You can define your custom rules directly on a `<FormKit />` input, or [globally](https://formkit.com/essentials/validation#adding-a-rule-globally) to use on any input. For this solution, we'll put the rule directly on the input.

Add your custom rules via the `:validation-rules` prop, which makes any rules inside available to the `validation` prop. We can optionally add custom validation messages via the `:validation-messages` prop.

```
<FormKit
  type="text"
  label="Pick a username"
  help="Type “foouser” to pass validation"
  validation="checkUsername"
  :validation-rules="rules"
  :validation-messages="{ checkUsername: 'Your custom message.' }"
/>
```

***Validation***

> Not only on submit but also after user removes focus from the input.

Validation in FormKit actually happens real-time. The only thing you need to do is define *when* to show the user the validation messages, whether real-time (`validation-visibility="live"`), on `blur` (default behavior), or on `submit`. This is known as [validation-visibility](https://formkit.com/essentials/validation#showing-errors).

***The full solution, with improved user experience (UX)***

For async rules, it's usually a good idea to show the user a loading spinner so they know an operation is happening real time, and feedback when the server responds. Here's a full example that:

1. Shows a loading spinner while the rule is validating.
2. Shows the validation message if the rule fails.
3. Shows a checkmark if the validation passes.

**Full solution:** https://formkit.link/9741f666840a11954233982ee189ab43

*Note:* In this contrived example, the backend is just mocked.